# Datatool gobbling spaces

Tags: spacing, datatool

I've come across a strange problem with `datatool`. If the first character of the first column of a row is immediately followed by a space, that space gets gobbled somehow.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
Sentence1,Sentence2,Sentence3
The child played a new game.,He played it three times with his friends.,He loved the game.
I visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
It's just as I remembered it.,I visited my childhood home last week.,My house has always been white.
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{sentences}{\jobname.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{sentences}{%
\sOne=Sentence1,\sTwo=Sentence2,\sThree=Sentence3}
{%
\sOne\par
\sTwo\par
\sThree\par
}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output.  Notice that the  sentence in column 1 of the CSV file (marked with the red arrow) has the gobbled space, but the exact same sentence in column 2 (marked with the blue arrow) doesn't have the space gobbled.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Sure seems like a bug. Strange that it has not been noticed before. TeXLive 2015 also reproduces this problem.

Comment: Any one letter word (or a single braced group) will show the same behavior. Apparently the macro for testing the beginning of a row eats two arguments, so a space in between them is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed. If you encounter it, make sure you have the latest version of [`datatool`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

---

### Original answer

The problem is with `\dtl@trim` which is supposed to trim the trailing space at the end of each line (caused by the end of line character). It's also supposed to discard the terminating `\par` that occurs on the final `\read` before the end of file is reached.

I think the following patch should fix the problem (but I need to test further to make sure it doesn't cause any unwanted side-effects). The argument of `\dtl@trim` is always a control sequence (set by `\read` for `\DTLloaddb`).

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\dtl@trim}[1]{%
  \if#1\par
    \def\@dtl@trmstr{}%
  \else
    \expandafter\@dtl@start@trim#1\@dtl@end@trim
  \fi
  \let#1=\@dtl@trmstr
}

\def\@dtl@start@trim#1 \@dtl@end@trim{%
 \def\@dtl@trmstr{#1}%
}

\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
Sentence1,Sentence2,Sentence3
The child played a new game.,He played it three times with his friends.,He loved the game.
I visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
It's just as I remembered it.,I visited my childhood home last week.,My house has always been white.
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\dtl@trim}[1]{%
  \if#1\par
    \def\@dtl@trmstr{}%
  \else
    \expandafter\@dtl@start@trim#1\@dtl@end@trim
  \fi
  \let#1=\@dtl@trmstr
}

\def\@dtl@start@trim#1 \@dtl@end@trim{%
 \def\@dtl@trmstr{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\DTLloaddb{sentences}{\jobname.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{sentences}{%
\sOne=Sentence1,\sTwo=Sentence2,\sThree=Sentence3}
{%
\sOne\par
\sTwo\par
\sThree\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Comment: Probably `\ifx\par#1` is better; it will fail if the line starts with `{\par}` or `\par`, however.

Comment: @egreg `#1` is a control sequence containing the line, so `#1` is never `\par`, but may be a control sequence whose replacement text is `\par`. Perhaps better would be something like `\def\@dtl@par{\par}` and then `\ifx#1\@dtl@par`.

Answer (score 3):

This does not fix the `datatool` bug, but rather shows an alternate approach using `readarray`.  It creates an array `\Sentence[<i>,<j>]`, where `i` and `j` are the row and column of the `\Sentence` array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,tikz}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
The child played a new game.,He played it three times with his friends.,He loved the game.
I visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
It's just as I remembered it.,I visited my childhood home last week.,My house has always been white.
\end{filecontents*}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\begin{document}
\readdef{\jobname.csv}\Sentences
\readarray\Sentences\Sentence[-,\ncols]
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,\SentenceROWS}
  {\foreach\y in {1,2,...,\SentenceCOLS}{\Sentence[\x,\y]\par}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven. There are plenty of workarounds I can use (and the real example is more complex than this) but this might be useful to others. It's certainly lower overhead than `datatool`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Understood.  I just find the `listofitems` package, which is incorporated into `readarray`, to be very versatile in these matters.  But I understand the real desire is to debug `datatool`.

Answer (score 3):

I propose a different patch than Nicola’s.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
Sentence1,Sentence2,Sentence3
The child played a new game.,He played it three times with his friends.,He loved the game.
I visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
It's just as I remembered it.,I visited my childhood home last week.,My house has always been white.
{}A visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
{Bbb} visited my childhood home last week.,It's just as I remembered it.,My house has always been white.
X,X,X
X
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@dtl@starttrim\@dtl@starttrim
\long\def\@dtl@starttrim#1{%
  \def\fix@dtl@starttrim@first{#1}%
  \futurelet\next\fix@dtl@starttrim@second
}
\def\fix@dtl@starttrim@second{%
  \if\noexpand\next\@sptoken
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\expandafter\saved@dtl@starttrim\expandafter{\fix@dtl@starttrim@first}{}}%
  {\expandafter\saved@dtl@starttrim\expandafter{\fix@dtl@starttrim@first}}%
}
\makeatother


\DTLloaddb{sentences}{\jobname.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{sentences}{%
\sOne=Sentence1,\sTwo=Sentence2,\sThree=Sentence3}
{%
\sOne\par
\sTwo\par
\sThree\par\kern1pt\hrule\kern1pt
}
\end{document}
```

The trimming macro checks whether the first token is followed by a space, but absorbing just one token (or braced group). It takes different actions according to whether the token is a space or not.

[image]

Comment: What are the relative merits/issues of each?

Comment: @AlanMunn Only Nicola can judge. However, `\if#1\par` looks *very* suspicious.

Comment: Now you're just being coy. ;-)

Comment: Your patch loses the grouping. Add `\show\sOne` at the start of the loop: `{}` is missing from `{}A visited...` and the group is stripped from `{Bbb} visited...`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Then a previous test for `\bgroup` is necessary.