# Error with latest version of datatool package

Tags: datatool

With the latest version of the datatool package, if I compile this file

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
  x,y
  11,12
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{table}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I get this error

```
./example.tex:9: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

In the pdf file it appears

```
,12
```

If I substitute 11 for 22 or 33 or ... I get the same error, but if I use any other number it compiles fine.

The file list is this

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
datatool.sty    2017/11/10 v2.28 (NLCT)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    xfor.sty    2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
  substr.sty    2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
datatool-base.sty    2017/11/10 v2.28 (NLCT)
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
datatool-fp.sty    2017/11/10 v2.28 (NLCT)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
```

Comment: ping Nicola `\dtl@trim #1->\def \@dtl@trmstr {}\if #1\par \else \expandafter \@dtl@start@tri` probably shouldn't be using `\if`

Comment: excellent test file thanks (+1), especially with the information about the problem applying only to repeated digits, that meant it was almost certain to be a rogue `\if` so it was just a matter of tracing to find which `\if` was causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in the last update to the package but I think a workaround is

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
  x,y
  11,12
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\def\dtl@trim#1{\def\@dtl@trmstr{}%
\if \par#1 \else \expandafter \@dtl@start@trim #1\@dtl@end@trim \fi
\let#1=\@dtl@trmstr}

\makeatother

\DTLloaddb{table}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the change here is just changing  `\if#1\par` to `\if\par#1`

Comment: Looks like it was introduced when fixing [bug report #123](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=123)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot excellent, so we can blame egreg.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot as egreg commented https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361994/datatool-gobbling-spaces/362125#comment892824_362125

Comment: I got confused because there was no redefinition of `\dtl@trim` in the patch. Forgot his answer was based on the previous definition of `\dtl@trim`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot although I did `\if\par#1` as a quick fix here that might not be safe (I am not sure of the context) as all commands are equal to `\if` this is the same as `\if\hbox#1` etc, and just testing if the first token in the line is a non-character. But perhaps `\par` is the only possible non character here

Comment: Unfortunately @egreg's patch strips the grouping occurring at the start of the line, which must be retained.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot probably `\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\par#1` but you might need more expandafters (how many macro levels can be involved here)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in v2.29 (2017-11-12). I've changed the way lines are read and trimmed. The code now locally changes `\endlinechar` to `\active` which makes it much simpler to trim the end of line character. Unlike spaces, there should only be one end of line character in the control sequence, and it will be at the end. (As documented, `datatool` doesn't support multiline CSV files. You need `datatooltk` for that.)